# Using XML as a datasource in d3js layout doesn't work in firefox

Tags: javascript, xml, d3.js, circle-pack

I'm trying to use an XML file as the datasource for my d3js visualization. It works in webkit based browsers, but not in firefox. I believe the error comes from the fact that a DOM element has no forEach function. 3djs seems to expect an array somewhere where it receives a DOM object. But I don't know where

My children function looks like this.

```
var bubble = d3.layout.pack()
    .sort(null)
    .children(function(d){
        var c = $("system",d);
        if (c.length<=0) c = $("planet",d);
        return c;
    })
```

[This](https://github.com/hannorein/oec_iphone/blob/master/data_iphone_9.1/systems.xml) is the XML document. I'm directly passing it to the d3js via

```
node = viz.selectAll(".node")
        .data(bubble.nodes(xmldata))
        .enter().append("g")
        .attr("class", "node")
```

[This](http://openexoplanetcatalogue.com/bubblechart.html) is a live demo of the code (which works in webkit, but not in firefox). And [here](https://github.com/hannorein/oec_web/blob/master/bubblechart.html) is the complete source code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [here](https://github.com/hannorein/oec_web/pull/1) for a fix.

The problem is that a jQuery query result is being passed directly as
nodes to the D3 layout.  D3 writes various properties, such as
"children", directly to each node.  This can cause issues if there is an
existing property with the same name being used for another purpose,
such as jQuery's "children" in this case.